# How to select UTXOs needed for covering a given ada amount using the Cardano Serialization Lib?

Tags: utxo, cardano-serialization-lib

Is there any prebuild method in Cardano Serialization Lib that allows to select some UTXOs that cover the balance needed for a transaction?

Or should i make a script that querys all the utxo in that addres and selects the first ones that covers this given amount?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are speaking about what we call *Coin Selection Algorithms* and they are described in [CIP2](https://cips.cardano.org/cips/cip2/).

There are several implementations floating around on Github, such as  [BerryPool implementation of the Random-Improve coin selection algorithm](https://github.com/Berry-Pool/nami-wallet/blob/main/src/lib/coinSelection.js) or [what Yoroi does](https://github.com/Emurgo/yoroi-frontend/blob/develop/packages/yoroi-extension/app/api/ada/transactions/shelley/transactions.js).

Comment: Yes i have seen Berrys implementation, but it semed a little bit too complex, and the CIP2 apears to be in haskell right? I did one script that only querys one by one until it gets the minimun and then the extra is sended back to the owner, i dont know if this is enought for my dapp or if should I use Berry implementation.

Comment: No, the CIP describes the algorithm, these are language agnostic.

Comment: +1 for the links to the coin selection CIP and the implementations!

Comment: The cardano-wallet's implementation in Haskell for coin selection can be found here: https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-wallet/blob/fe7632e44bfb6be9171069e3bf70b6a4e43bf6ff/lib/core/src/Cardano/Wallet/Primitive/CoinSelection.hs

Comment: @MarekMahut-StakeNuts CIP20 states "Problems relating to network fees, and how to adjust coin selections to pay for such fees, are outside the scope of this article." Any ideas how to solve that?